# How to disable the resume button in Media player if User clicked it ONce

Tags: android

I had Used This Function in Media Player for producing Alert Dialog and respond for it when user Resumed the video

```
  setPositiveButton-->"Start Over"
  setNegitiveButton-->"Resume"   

        public abstract void onClick (DialogInterface dialog, int which){
          //what i need is disable the "RESUME" if user clicked it once...
```

I am pasting you my whole function here Please modify it ...

```
   private void showResumeDialog(Context context, final int bookmark) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    builder.setTitle(R.string.resume_playing_title);
    builder.setMessage(String.format(
            context.getString(R.string.resume_playing_message),
            GalleryUtils.formatDuration(context, bookmark / 1000)));
    builder.setOnCancelListener(new OnCancelListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
            onCompletion();
        }
    });
    builder.setPositiveButton(
            R.string.resume_playing_resume, new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            mVideoView.seekTo(bookmark);
            startVideo();
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton(
            R.string.resume_playing_restart, new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            startVideo();
        }
    });
    builder.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check It Here is your code

```
Int flag=0;
private void showResumeDialog(Context context, final int bookmark) {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        builder.setTitle(R.string.resume_playing_title);
        builder.setMessage(String.format(
            context.getString(R.string.resume_playing_message),
            GalleryUtils.formatDuration(context, bookmark / 1000)));
    builder.setOnCancelListener(new OnCancelListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
            onCompletion();
        }
    });
    builder.setPositiveButton(
            R.string.resume_playing_resume, new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            flag++;
            If(flag>1)
            {
                mVideoView.seekTo(bookmark);
                startVideo();
            }else{

                //Do Nothing
            }
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton(
            R.string.resume_playing_restart, new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            startVideo();
        }
    });
    builder.show();
}
```

Good Luck...

Comment: can u please check my Edited Post @user2846678

Comment: I had Checked Your latest edit It was not working But thanks for trying to help me out Here, Thanks a lot
I'll Explain My problem clearly help me If You can....
When we clicked on any video it takes some time to load right,Mean while i.e, while loading if you clicked on anywhere on the screen It was dropping that Input Event ,It was not able to Handle it, Now I want to handle/disable/anything but i want to stop that app crash
Pls Help me if u can Thanks in advance..... @user2846678